# Folder is in $INC but module loads from other location

Tags: perl, docker

I need to test my project with new module version.
But for some reason Perl can not load it.

```
docker-compose run -v /data/projects/My-Module:/perl5lib project-container perl -I/perl5lib -MMy::Module -e 'print $INC{"My/Module.pm"}'
```

It must print

```
/perl5lib
```

But in fact it prints

```
/usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/My/Module.pm
```

Same result with

```
docker-compose run -e PERL5LIB=/perl5lib -v /data/projects/My-Module:/perl5lib project-container perl -MMy::Module -e 'print $INC{"My/Module.pm"}'
```

Please help me to find what could be the issue.

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896
```

Comment: Does `/perl5lib/My/Module.pm` exist? Does the relevant user/group have permissions to read `/perl5lib`, `/perl5lib/My` and `/perl5lib/My/Module.pm`? Are any of `/perl5lib`, `/perl5lib/My` or `/perl5lib/My/Module.pm` symlinks?

Comment: What happens if you change `-MMy::Module` to `-e 'require "/perl5lib/My/Module.pm";'`?

Comment: Can you show the output of just `print "@INC"`?

Comment: @choroba There's no reason to believe there's a bug in `perl`'s handling of `-I/perl5lib`.

Comment: @ikegami the mapping from -I to `@INC` is not straightforward

Comment: @ysth, In the sense that it might add more than just the one directory, but even if `/perl5lib` doesn't exist or can't be read, `-I/perl5lib` will still get added.

Comment: I can confirm that `/perl5lib` is first item in `@INC` and `/data/projects/My-Module` has 777 permissions. Now I figured out what was the issue. If I use other name (e.g. `/libperl` ) then `/perl5lib` for mounting module sources everything is ok. Very-very-very strange issue.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. No problem with usage `/perl5lib` name as mount point. Problem was that docker-compose already has volume mounted to `/perl5lib` which points to another location

Answer (score 1):

With this command (which should be more-or-less equivalent to what you are doing)

```
docker run perl:5.28 perl -I/xyz -V
```

Regardless `/xyz` exists or not within the container instance, I can visually confirm that `/xyz` is the first entry of `@INC`:

```
  ...
  Compiled at Aug 15 2019 02:34:38
  @INC:
    /xyz
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.2/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.2
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28.2/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28.2
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.2/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.2
```

Given by your message that `My/Module.pm` got required from an alternative place, I'd guess that your `/perl5lib` is empty, or simply does not contain `My/Module.pm`  -- or somehow that alternative path comes first then your `/perl5lib`. Not sure how that would be the case, but I'm trying to enumerate some possibilities.

Anyway, you should be able to inspect the content of `/perl5lib` by running

```
docker-compose run -v /data/projects/My-Module:/perl5lib project-container find /perl5lib
```

(I guess `find` command is available in your container, but if not, try `ls -R` or something similar...)

Last... in case you are using Docker on macOS -- which I cannot tell from the information you provided -- you need to verify that the `/data/projects/My-Module` is in the list of "File Sharing" preference. Otherwise that folder cannot be mounted.

Comment: `ls -lR` would be more useful than `find` as it shows file types and permissions